# VueJs how to make pagination with limiter and range..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-4, pagination, vue.js

I have code like this :

```js
var demoList = new Vue({
  el: '#demoList',
  data: {
    items: [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Tom"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Kate"
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Jack"
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Jill"
    }, {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "aa"
    }, {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "bb"
    }, {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "cc"
    }, {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "dd"
    }, {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Tom"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Kate"
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Jack"
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Jill"
    }, {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "aa"
    }, {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "bb"
    }, {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "cc"
    }, {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "dd"
    }, ],
    loading: false,
    order: 1,
    searchText: null,
    ccn: null,
    currentPage: 0,
    itemsPerPage: 2,
    resultCount: 0
  },
  computed: {
    totalPages: function() {
      console.log(Math.ceil(this.resultCount / this.itemsPerPage) + "totalPages");
      return Math.ceil(this.resultCount / this.itemsPerPage);

    }
  },
  methods: {
    setPage: function(pageNumber) {
      this.currentPage = pageNumber;
      console.log(pageNumber);
    }
  },
  filters: {
    paginate: function(list) {
      this.resultCount = this.items.length;
      console.log(this.resultCount + " Result count");
      console.log(this.currentPage + " current page");
      console.log(this.itemsPerPage + " items per page");
      console.log(this.totalPages + " Total pages 2");
      if (this.currentPage >= this.totalPages) {
        this.currentPage = Math.max(0, this.totalPages - 1);
      }
      var index = this.currentPage * this.itemsPerPage;
      console.log(index + " index");
      console.log(this.items.slice(index, index + this.itemsPerPage));
      return this.items.slice(index, index + this.itemsPerPage);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
a {
  color: #999;
}
.current {
  color: red;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demoList">
  <div class="containerTable">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr class="header">
          <th>
            <div><a @click="sortvia('provider_name')">Provider</a>
            </div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="item in items | paginate">
          <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="pageNumber in totalPages">
      <a href="#" @click="setPage(pageNumber)">{{ pageNumber+1 }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Im stuck trying to create a pager with vuejs, so I was wonder if anyone can appoint an example of how to make a pager like this if is possible "1-2-3-4-5 ... 55" ??, thanks again for any help.

Comment: Can you explain further what your desired output is?

Comment: I want in pagination number like this "1-2-3-4-5 ... last"  not all 1-2-3-4-5-6 -7-8

Comment: you could do an ngif="$index - page < 5"

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Check out this code:

https://jsfiddle.net/os7hp1cy/48/

html:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="pageNumber in totalPages" 
        v-if="Math.abs(pageNumber - currentPage) < 3 || pageNumber == totalPages - 1 || pageNumber == 0">
    <a href="#" @click="setPage(pageNumber)"  
       :class="{current: currentPage === pageNumber, last: (pageNumber == totalPages - 1 && Math.abs(pageNumber - currentPage) > 3), first:(pageNumber == 0 && Math.abs(pageNumber - currentPage) > 3)}">
       {{ pageNumber+1 }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
a.first::after {
  content:'...'
}

a.last::before {
  content:'...'
}
```

Basically, it only shows pagination that is within 2 pages of the current page.  Then it will also show page 1 and the last page, and will put `"..."` before or after the number with CSS.  So if you are on page 10, it will show:

`1...  8 9 10 11 12 ...21`

Comment: I tried this code in my example and for some reason it gives me a warning:
[Vue warn]: Property or method "paginate" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 
(found in root instance)
I'm having the paginate function in filters,which are inside methods.

Comment: I'm getting an error from `eslint`: `no-use-v-if-with-v-for`

Answer (score 6):

I've forked @Jeff's code and make a working version for Vue 2 due to this filter migration https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Filters-Outside-Text-Interpolations-removed.

paginate method is moved to computed:

```
paginate: function() {
        if (!this.users || this.users.length != this.users.length) {
            return
        }
        this.resultCount = this.users.length
        if (this.currentPage >= this.totalPages) {
          this.currentPage = this.totalPages
        }
        var index = this.currentPage * this.itemsPerPage - this.itemsPerPage
        return this.users.slice(index, index + this.itemsPerPage)
    }
```

WARNING: I didn't apply the text filter, just the pagination first.

https://jsfiddle.net/c1ghkw2p/