# vueJs paginate and filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, vue.js

how I can handle filtering with paginate in vueJs [more detail please check](https://jsfiddle.net/badvz/xakvbzur/6/)

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4" v-for="item in items | limitBy count offset | filterBy name in 'name'">
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to filter for just one result, you can reorder your filters thus:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4" v-for="item in items | filterBy name in 'name' | limitBy count offset">
```

If this is not the intended output, try changing the `limitBy` arguments.

The way the filters were set up earlier, only those items were being searched for the target string that were displayed on the page, i.e., only a single item was being searched.  For example, the first page displays 'Kathy Sparks'.  If the target string matched, for e.g., if it contained 'kat', then the name would show.  Otherwise, suppose the target string were 'katt', no results would be displayed.

Comment: hy Adeel Zafar Soomro oh yahh sorry, but I have one quetions about vueJs paginate please check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596389/vuejs-how-to-make-pagination-with-limiter-and-range

Comment: hy Adeel Zafar Soomro oh okay.. but I have one quetions about pagination in vueJs please check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596389/vuejs-how-to-make-pagination-with-limiter-and-range