# how to make paging in vuejs to limit the number specified

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, pagination, vue.js

Im stuck trying to create a pager with vuejs, so I was wonder if anyone can appoint an example of how to make a pager like this if is possible "1-2-3-4-5 ... 55" ??, thanks again for any help [please check this out](https://jsfiddle.net/badvz/os7hp1cy/46/)

```
<li v-for="pageNumber in totalPages">
  <a href="#" @click="setPage(pageNumber)" v-class="current: currentPage === pageNumber">{{ pageNumber+1 }}</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VueJs how to make pagination with limiter and range..?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596389/vuejs-how-to-make-pagination-with-limiter-and-range)