# How to limit iteration of elements in `v-for`

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building a small application in `Vuejs 2.0` I'm having approx 15 iterating elements I want to limit the `v-for` for only 5 elements and can have more buttons to display the whole list. Is there any possibilities?

Comment: show us what you've tried...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VueJs how to make pagination with limiter and range..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596389/vuejs-how-to-make-pagination-with-limiter-and-range)

Answer (score 218, accepted):

You can try this code

```vue
<div v-if="showLess">
    <div v-for="value in array.slice(0, 5)"></div>
</div> 
<div v-else> 
    <div v-for="value in array"></div>
</div> 
<button @click="showLess = false"></button>
```

You will only have 5 elements in the new array.

Update:
Tiny change that makes this solution work with both arrays and objects

```
<div v-if="showLess">
  <div v-for="(value,index) in object">
    <template v-if="index <= 5"></template>
  </div>
</div> 
<div v-else> 
  <div v-for="value in object"></div>
</div> 
<button @click="showLess = false"></button>
```

Comment: As stated, this only works on **arrays**, objects will throw errors.

Comment: @Fusseldieb Yes.. That's why it is very good practice to save your data **as arrays** even when you got data as object. It will help you to work with Vuejs in better way.

Comment: or you can make a condition in the cycle itself

`<div v-for="value in (showLess ? array : array.slice(0, 5))></div>
<button @click="showLess = false"></button>`

Comment: it's a bad practice including a v-if and v-for on same element - try avoid and add a wrapper with the v-if condition

Comment: @unplugged answer below is the correct answer, this is bad practise

Comment: This will lead to doubled code for the inner loop, better use a computed property as stated in the second answer, this way your html code is not doubled.

Answer (score 48):

Am I too late?
You can solve this using computed properties:

```vue
<div v-for="value in computedObj">{{value}}</div>
<button @click="limit = null">Show more</button>
```

Then in data:

```
data(){
  return {
    object:[], // your original data
    limit: 5 // or any number you wish to limit to
  }
}
```

And finally in your computed properties:

```
computed:{
  computedObj(){
    return this.limit ? this.object.slice(0,this.limit) : this.object
  }
}
```

When your click the button, the limit is cleared and the whole data is shown/returned

Answer (score 7):

you can try this solution to...

```
<div  class="body-table  div-table" v-for="(item,index) in items"  :key="item.id" v-if="items && items.length > 0 && index <= limitationList">....
```

and set your limit in data

```
data() {
  return {
    limitationList:5
  };
},
```

and set a function in you btn

```
  <button  @click="updateLimitation(limitationList)">
    show {{limitationList == 5 ? 'more' : 'less'}}
  </button>
```

and this your methods

```
updateLimitation(limitationList){
  if (this.limitationList == this.items.length) {
    this.limitationList = 5
  }else{
    this.limitationList = this.items.length
  }
}
```

i hope useful for you...

Comment: This solutions isn't good as vue's v-if will leave a blank comment for every element that didn't pass limit check. So you'll end up having many "<!---->" in your DOM.

Answer (score 2):

This is what `computed` was made for (I'm using `script setup`):

```
const paginatedList = computed(() => {
    // for arrays
    return yourArray.slice(0,5)

    // for objects/proxies such as reactive, refs, other computed
    // return yourObject.value.slice(0,5)
})
```

render it in a `v-for` loop:

```
<div v-for="item in paginatedList">
    <p>{{ item }}</p>
</div
```

Answer (score 0):

for resolve that problem u can computed limit list in computed method

like this

```
<div  class="body-table  div-table" v-for="(item,index) in filterItems"  :key="item.id">
....

<script>

export default {
  data() {
     return {
       items: [],
       limitationList:5
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filterItems () {
      return this.items && this.items.length > 0 && (this.items.length - 1) <= this.limitationList  // or any condition u want 
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

I hope useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, check that if your rendering list you must hide the root section in the iteration `<li>`.

```
 <ul role="list">
     <li v-for="(actor,index) in this.cast" :key="actor.id" :class="{'your-hidden-class': index>5}">
       <div v-if="index <= 5">
         <img v-if="actor.profile_path" :src="'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original' + actor.profile_path" alt="" />
         <img v-else src="/images/image-not-found.png" alt="" />
         <div>
           <div>
             <h3>{{ actor.original_name }}</h3>
             <p>{{ actor.character }}</p>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

{{index}}

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div v-for="(contact, index) in allContacts" v-if="index < limitNumber" id="contacts">
  <p>{{index}}</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script>
        new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data:{
      filterId:'10',
      limitNumber:10,
      allContacts:[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},],
    },
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).