# How to configure the first 3 values in v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How to start a `v-for` loop

Example A array given :

```
array = [dog,cat,e,f,g];
```

I want use v-for loop which will start looping take the first 3 value.

Thank you.

Comment: I think the answer that you are looking for is there
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46622209/how-to-limit-iteration-of-elements-in-v-for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit iteration of elements in V-for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46622209/how-to-limit-iteration-of-elements-in-v-for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a computed property that returns the first 3 elements of the array.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  template: '<ul><li v-for="item of subArray">{{ item }}</li></ul>',
  data: {
    array: ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
  },
  computed: {
    subArray(){ return this.array.slice(0,3) }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a v-if statement that checks if the index of the element is less than 3.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the built-in `index` feature

```
<template v-for="(element, index) in array">
  <p v-if="index <= 3">[[ index ]]</p>
</template>
```

and you're done,